# looking to integrate formula into one and present it in a single array (python)

Tags: python

```
i = [2,3,4]
interest = [1.08,1.0824,1.09,1.095]

yr2 = (interest[0] * interest[1])**(1./i[0]) - 1.
yr3 = (interest[0] * interest[1] * interest[2])**(1./i[1]) - 1.
yr4 = (interest[0] * interest[1] * interest[2] * interest[3])**(1./i[2]) - 1.
```

I declared 2 arrays (above) but i am looking to display my answer in this format:

```
yield = [yr2,yr3,yr4]
```

Comment: integrate like this `[yr2, yr3, yr4] = [(interest[0] * interest[1])**(1./i[0]) - 1., (interest[0] * interest[1] * interest[2])**(1./i[1]) - 1., (interest[0] * interest[1] * interest[2] * interest[3])**(1./i[2]) - 1.]`

can you specify what is expected ?

Comment: 2-year: 〖(1.08 × 1.0824)〗^(1/2) – 1 = 8.12%
3-year: 〖(1.08 × 1.0824 ×1.09)〗^(1/3) – 1 = 8.41%
4-year: 〖(1.08 × 1.0824 ×1.09 ×1.095)〗^(1/4) – 1 = 8.68%

Comment: i want to convert my workings into a general formula where i can just extract values from range i and interest to print results for year 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

```
# data
i = [2,3,4]
interest = [1.08,1.0824,1.09,1.095]

def count_interests(bar, interest):
    """
    Returns a list:
    [(interest[0] * interest[1]), (interest[0] * interest[1] * interest[2]),
    (interest[0] * interest[1] * interest[2] * interest[3])]
    """
    res = []
    compound = [interest[0]]
    print(f'first compound {compound}')
    for i in range(len(bar)): # [0,1,2]
        inter = compound[i] * interest[i+1]
        compound.append(inter)
    print(compound)
    return compound

compound = count_interests(i, interest)
compound.pop(0)
print(compound)
# [1.168992, 1.2742012800000002, 1.3952504016000002]
zipped = zip(i, compound)

def yr(zip):
    res = []
    for k, v in zip:
        temp = v ** (1./k) - 1
        res.append(temp)
    return res

result = yr(zipped)
```

Result

```
[0.0811993340730468, 0.08412496573593131, 0.08683355662001646]
```

Comment: You're right, missed `return` in `yr` function, Try again

Comment: Did it help you?